# filtering a recordlist User.IsInRole MVC

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, permissions, isinrole

I have 16 different roles and I'm trying to filter a list according to a users role.  I was hoping there was a way to filter this using LINQ but I'm not sure of the best approach for this.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(int? Group, int? ListDept, int DivisionID)
    {

        LoginViewModel login = new LoginViewModel();

        login.GroupID = Group;
        login.ListDeptID = ListDept;
        login.DivisionID = DivisionID;

        bool rolecheck1 = false;
        bool rolecheck2 = false;
        bool rolecheck3 = false;

        rolecheck1 = User.IsInRole("Role1");
        rolecheck2 = User.IsInRole("Role2");
        rolecheck3 = User.IsInRole("Role3");

        if (rolecheck1 == true && login.GroupID == 1)
        {
            login.GroupID = 1;
        }
        if (rolecheck2 == true && login.GroupID == 2)
        {
            login.GroupID = 2;
        }
        if (rolecheck3 == true && login.GroupID == 3)
        {
            login.GroupID = 3;
        }
        Session["Login"] = login;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Case");
    }
```

After the Post it goes to an index page where I'm trying to filter those lists and I think I'm going about this completely wrong :/.  Here is the Index page where I'm loading the record list.  I also filter for a case that is assigned to a person and it works fine.  But how do I filter those permissions to show also a record that a person has the permission for?

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        LoginViewModel login = new LoginViewModel();
        login = (LoginViewModel)Session["Login"];

        // uses the DirectorySearcher to find a users email address to use the "assignedTo" for filtering
        var assignedto = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
        string emailAddr = null;
        try
        {
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
            searcher.Filter = string.Format("sAMAccountName={0}", assignedto);
            SearchResult user = searcher.FindOne();
            emailAddr = user.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            TempData["loginErrorMessage"] = String.Format("Directory Services is down or you have an invalid account");
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        CaseListViewModel cases = new CaseListViewModel();
        cases.OpenCases = db.Cases.Where(c => c.StatusID == 1 && c.AssignedTo == emailAddr || login.DivisionID == c.DivisionID && login.GroupID == c.GroupID);
        cases.ClosedCases = db.Cases.Where(c => c.StatusID == 2);


        // Before added email filtering for assigned to
        //cases.OpenCases = db.Cases.Where(c => c.StatusID == 1);

        // Loop that checks each case and compares DateTime.Now to Lockout Stamp to unlock cases

        foreach (var cased in cases.OpenCases)
        {
            DateTime LockoutDate = new DateTime();

            if (cased.Lockout_TS.HasValue)
            {
                LockoutDate = (DateTime)cased.Lockout_TS;
            }

            if (cased.LockCase == true)
            {
                bool shouldUnlock = (DateTime.Now - LockoutDate).TotalMinutes > 15;

                //if yes, then unlock it
                if (shouldUnlock)
                {
                    cased.LockCase = false;
                    cased.Lockout_TS = null;
                }


            }
        }
        // End Loop
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(cases);
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can record the association of roles to group in a dictionary and use Linq to determine the group for the user based on their role.

```
  var roleGroupMap = new Dictionary<string, int> {
    ["Role1"] = 1,
    ["Role2"] = 2,
    ["Role3"] = 3
  };

 ...

  var userRole = roleGroupMap.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x => User.IsInRole(x));
  if (userRole != null) {
    login.GroupID = roleGroupMap[userRole];
  }
```

This model will accommodate the user having a single role. If users can have more than one role, then the `LoginViewModel` will need to be modified to record a collection of groups and the associated groups.

With a collection of `GroupIDs`:

```
roleGroupMap.Keys
  .Where(x => User.IsInRole(x))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(x => login.GroupIDs.Add(x => User.IsInRole(x)))
```

Comment: This is perfect!!! I understand what your doing.  But it doesn't like "  ["Role1"] = 1,
    ["Role2"] = 2,
    ["Role3"] = 3" this part and is giving me a syntax error, so I changed it around to "{"Role1, 1}, {"Role2"}, etc... Can I set the Value of Role1 to 1, so I can compare it to the GroupID?

Thanks again so much.

Comment: The syntax for initializing the dictionary is new in C# 6. What you have is fine for setting up the dictionary using C# 5.

Comment: Since I'm only able to compare with one value and I do need multiple permissions I have created a collection in my LoginViewModel.  To make this work do I need to create a loop to check for the multiple permissions?  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks HashPsi -- It doesn't like the "(x => User.IsInRole(x)));".  It is giving me a "Cannot convert lambda expression to type"MSC.Models.Group' because it is not a delegate type".  I'm using " public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }" in my viewmodel.  Does that look correct?

Comment: You can try setting the type for the Groups property to IList<int>